# How to get back from the web view in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

i am new to iOS .In my project have two view controller namely FirstViewController and Webviewcontroller. In my firstviewcontroller i set one button. when i click that button its moved to webviewcontroller and load one sample website. In top navigation bar of my webviewcontroller have two buttons for handling the website pages the code like below

```
//for handle the previous page
- (void) buttonGoBack
{
   if ([_webView canGoBack]) {
       [_webView goBack];
   }
}

//for handle the next page
- (void) buttonGoForward
{
    if ([_webView canGoForward]) {
        [_webView goForward];
    }
}
```

now what i want is......when i click the previous button in the top its move to previous page of web view. what i need is when the web view finished their page that time i click the previous page its go to previous view controller.this is my need. sorry for the bad english.thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if canGoBack returns NO pop the viewController by `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES` 
Or if have prsentViewController then call `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]`

Comment: i tried but its through error like No visible @interface for 'UINavigationController' declares the selector 'popRootViewController'

Comment: So did u push webviewcontroller or present... If u present then u need to dimissViewController by calling [self dismissViewController]

Comment: this one also not working ...when i call this method then i click the button its not responding

Comment: Its mean u pushed it so first option should work popViewController make sure u are calling same

Comment: Thanks C_X  on that day i using push view controller. But now i need to use present view controller. After long long ago i remind your guides now.its worked great for me. Thanks lot. I will give you green

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void) buttonGoForward
{
  if ([_webView canGoForward])
  {
    [_webView goForward];
  }
  else
  {
     // pop webviewcontroller or dismiss depending on how you have launched webviewcontroller screen
  }
}
```

Comment: in the else part i push my previous view controller 'code' ViewController *replaceView = [ViewController initWithNibFromBundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:replaceView animated:YES]; .......but its move to previous viewcontroller then i click the navigation button in the viewcontroller its again move to webviewcontroller

Comment: not push you should use [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated: NO]; in else as you had already pushed you webviewcontrolller and you want to come back to first viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
//for handle the previous page
- (void) buttonGoBack {
    if ([_webView canGoBack]) {
        [_webView goBack];
    } else {
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: ya great...its worked for me...thank you so much Fahim Parkar

Comment: @Roby : good to know it worked. Please mark answer as accepted if it solved your question...